# How to re-initialize a vector in a while-loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, initialization, stdvector

I am doing some exercises in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). I am trying to make a simple game which requires continuous input in a vector from the user.

I tried to reinitialize the vector. I used in the `while(1)` loop and tried to `clear()` it too.

```
vector<int> user;                 // initialize vector
while (1)
{                                 
    for (int guess; cin >> guess;)// looping
    {                             // user input
        user.push_back(guess);
    }
    if (user.size() != 4)         // check if user put exactly 4 numbers
    {         
        cerr << "Invalid input";
        return 1;
    }
    //...                        // doing some stuff with "int bulls"
    if (bulls == 4)
    {
        break;
    }
}    // now need to go back with emty vector, so that the user can input guesses again
```

In my terminal, it is looping forever or it is stopping in a condition I put for invalid input.

Comment: Put the clear right after while if you want to clear it before reading input.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop because of

```
for(int guess; cin >> guess;)
```

where you `push_back` to *user* vector until `std::cin` fails.

You probably want to have `4` user input. If so try the following, by which you do not need to clear the vector as in each `while` loop you create a new one.

```
while (true)
{   
    std::vector<int> user;
    user.reserve(4); // reserve memory which helps not to have unwanted reallocations
    int guess;
    while(cin >> guess &&  user.size() != 4)
        user.emplace_back(guess);

    // doing some stuff with "int bulls"
    if (bulls == 4) {
        break;
    }
}
```